# How to make jquery sortable items sort only the sortable items and not the non sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have sortable items:

```
<div class="sortItems">
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 1</div>
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 2</div>
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 3</div>
<div class="sortPhotos ">ITEM 4</div>
<div class="sortPhotos ">ITEM 5</div>
</div>

$(".sortItems").sortable({
 items : ' > .sortPhotos',
 items : ':not(.nonSortable)'
```

});

My problem is this, I only want to sort ITEM 4 and ITEM 5 and I don't want them to cross over the ".nonSortable" divs. Meaning, I don't want ITEM 4 or ITEM 5 to be in front or in the middle of any of the the ".nonSortable" divs.

UPDATE:

I don't want this to happen:

```
<div class="sortItems">
<div class="sortPhotos ">ITEM 4</div>
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 1</div>
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 2</div>
<div class="sortPhotos ">ITEM 5</div>
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 3</div>
</div>
```

I want the sortable divs to be the only items sortable. I can only do this:

```
<div class="sortItems">
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 1</div>
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 2</div>
<div class="sortPhotos nonSortable">ITEM 3</div>
<div class="sortPhotos ">ITEM 5</div>
<div class="sortPhotos ">ITEM 4</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: dont understand your problem,Please explain properly

Comment: create jsfiddle please

Comment: does `items:"div:not(.nonSortable)"` work? there is an example here https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items